# Is it possible to create a git patch from one directory and apply that patch to the different directory ?,

Tags: git, github, git-patch

I am trying to create a patch from one directory and apply that patch to the different directory, provided both the directory contains same files.

For Example:
 Consider, the repo-1 **/local/mnt/workspace/New_version/sample_dir/** contains File1, File2 and File3.

Consider, repo-2 **/local/mnt/workspace/old_version/** contains same set of files mentioned in repo-1.

Now, I am trying to create a patch set from repo-1 and trying to apply it on the repo-2, which throws error due to path conflicts.

Is there any possible way to meet my requirement? Please help !

Answer (score 3):

You can use `-p` to remove directories and `--directory=<root>` for this:

```
   -p<n>
       Remove <n> leading slashes from traditional diff paths. The default is 1.

   --directory=<root>
       Prepend <root> to all filenames. If a "-p" argument was also passed, it is applied before prepending the new root.

       For example, a patch that talks about updating a/git-gui.sh to b/git-gui.sh can be applied to the file in the working tree modules/git-gui/git-gui.sh by running git apply --directory=modules/git-gui.
```